# Join tables to find distinct rows if any duplicate columns on join are fetched on the basis of date

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I have two tables I need to join these table and there is a possibility that joined table might return duplicate rows but there is column updated date which will be unique so I need to fetch record from these tables and get distinct records from second table

Table-1

| **Id** | **AccountKey** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 13 |

Table-2

| **Rolekey** | **Account Key** | **Date ** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 2-12-2022 |
| 2 | 12 | 1-12-2022 |
| 3 | 13 | 1-12-2022 |

In the above table I except the result as below
Expections:-

| Id | AccountKey | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | 2-12-2022 |
| 2 | 13 | 1-12-2022 |

But I am getting all the rows means 3, below is what I tried

```
select table1.id,table1.accountkey,table2.date 
from table1 table1 
JOIN table2 table2 
ON table1.accountkey=table2.accountkey
```

Comment: Please provide DDL + DML commands, thank you

Comment: are you trying to group by id and accountKey?

Comment: I want something if there is something exact match during the JOINS then consider the latest updated/inserted record as per date @learning

Comment: @learning -- I am not really sure thats the use case for me now

Comment: It's quite difficult to help if you're unsure about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we're grouping by id and accountKey
Query below will get as your desired result.

```
SELECT a.id, a.accountKey, MAX(b.cdate)
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.accountKey = b.accountKey
GROUP BY a.id, a.accountKey
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
drop table if exists one;
drop table if exists two;

create table one
(
  ID         [Int]
, AccountKey [Int]
)
;

insert into one
values (1, 12)
     , (2, 13)
;

create table two
(
  Rolekey    [Int]
, AccountKey [Int]
, Date       [Date]
)
;

insert into two
values (1, 12, '2022-12-02')
     , (2, 12, '2022-12-01')
     , (3, 13, '2022-12-01')
;

select one.id
     , one.AccountKey
     , max(Date) as Date
from one, two
where one.AccountKey = two.AccountKey
group by one.id
       , one.AccountKey
;
```

Comment: This doesn't differ to the already given answer except for using obsolete "join" syntax which should never be proposed as an answer.